# Load a new instance of component on click

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

I have a component binding within a modal:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">New</button>
<div data-bind="component: 'wizard'" id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog"></div>
```

I want to show a new wizard whenever the button is clicked. However, in this case, component is being loaded once and clicking on `New` button always pops up the modal with previous values.

Is it possible to load a new instance of `wizard` component every time I click `New` button?

Comment: I believe it is an  [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).Could you please add some code to understand which are the previous values?

Comment: Most likely, you just want a function that resets the values. Call the function as part of the process that opens the modal.